# Problema con Cors Node JS - Front en otro dominio

Tags: nodejs, cors

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición post a mi aplicación de node, que está alojada en un dominio diferente al del cliente, pero cuando trato de hacer la petición recibo este error en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un archivo setting.js donde añado CORS (Donde ya intente de dos manera, con app.use(cors())) y de la otra forma configurando express. Sin embargo, ninguna de las dos formas me ha funcionado:

```
const morgan = require('morgan')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
function config(app) {
    app.disabled('x-powered-by');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-COntrol-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
    })
    app.use(express.json({limit:'10mb',extended:true}));
    app.use(express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
        limit:'10mb'
    }));
}

module.exports = config;
```

O simplemente reemplazando lo del access-control-allow-origin por app.use(cors())

Aclaro, la aplicación la tengo corriendo en un servidor apache (Por si sirve dicha información)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses `"cors"`
La especificación es compleja y te ahorras tener que implementarla desde cero.

```javascript
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors(options));
```